# Why my code doesn't work on IE and it work fine in Chrome? Where do I make mistake?

Tags: html

Why my code doesn't work on IE and it work fine in Chrome? Where do I make mistake? I want it load in Internet Explorer, not chrome. Is it because "window.onload=new function" not work on Internet explorer?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
       
    
  
   <div id="time" style="font-size: 2em">+m:+s</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload=new function strtWatch() {
   
  let time, intervalId;
       new function strtWatch(i) {
    time = -1;
    incrementTime();
    intervalId = setInterval(incrementTime, 1000);        
  }
 strtWatch();

        function incrementTime() {
            time++;
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
                    ("0" + Math.trunc(time / 60)).slice(-2) +
                    ":" + ("0" + (time % 60)).slice(-2);
               t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
i="0" + i;
}

}
}

</script>
```

Comment: What is the error do you get in IE? What version of IE?

Comment: @JonP There's no error, The timer just doesn't move. It stays at 00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't support ES6, which includes keywords such as `let`.

IE hasn't been updated in nearly a decade.  If you still need to support IE, consider using a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io).